# Retrieving objects from HashMap in Java?

Tags: java

I have a HashMap which holds studentIds as key and student objects as values,

```
HashMap<Integer, Student> hashMap = hashTables.buildHash(students);

public static HashMap<Integer, Student> buildHash(Student[] students) {
            HashMap<Integer, Student> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Student>();
            for (Student s : students) hashMap.put(s.getId(), s);
            return hashMap;
       }
```

the below code gets each KeyValue pair and s.getValue() returns a student object which is comprised of an id and an string name, how can i retrieve/print those values (student.int, student.name);

```
for(Map.Entry s : hashMap.entrySet())
    System.out.print(s.getKey()+" "+s.getValue());
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to use the parameterized type for the entry:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Student> s : hashMap.entrySet())
    System.out.print(s.getKey()+" "+s.getValue().getId()+" "+s.getValue().getName());
```

(note that it's impossible for a class to have a field named "int" because that's a language keyword).

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: only because I was using the OP's syntax-violating infor about his class' structure

Comment: Of course, I realized the humoristic aspect of it. Just that it's better to help than to mock :) Mind also that in the `HashMap` population code he uses a getter, so probably his `id` and `name` are private, as they should be.

Answer (score 3):

Just implement `toString` in Student and the code you posted will work as-is:

```
public class Student {
    ...
    public String toString() {
      return "ID = " + this.id + ", name = " + this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway that i could retrieve the int and string values of the object?

Comment: See Michael Borgwardt's answer on that, he has it covered. The point is to use type parameters on the `Map.Entry`'s declaration. Then you can freely write `e.getValue().getId()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive this by..

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Student> s : hashMap.entrySet()){
    System.out.print(Long.valueof(s.getKey())+""+String.valueof(s.getValue().getName()));
}
```